# SQL Server auto increment a column without primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to auto increment a column in SQL Server WITHOUT it being a primary key?

If yes how can this be done.

Thanks

Comment: Sure - the column just has to be declared as `INT IDENTITY` (or BIGINT) - that's all there is to it. No requirement for it to be the primary key - none at all...

Comment: What constrained you from... trying?

Comment: @adrian: ... just not on your production system , please! :-)

Comment: @marc_s Good call! How about the good ol' sandbox DB? What, you don't have one??

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Yes. There is no requirement that `IDENTITY` columns be made a primary key.

```
CREATE TABLE T
(
X INT PRIMARY KEY,
Y INT IDENTITY(1,1)
)
```

Though I'm not sure when this would be useful. If you have a natural key that you want to use as the PK then you would probably want to put a unique constraint on the surrogate alternate key anyway.

For purposes of setting up FK relationships SQL Server doesn't care if the column(s) is the PK or not it just requires a unique index on it/them.

Comment: It's an easy way to remember the sequence in which the records were added to the table.

Comment: @Larry, so is a CreatedDate with default(getdate()), which is far more meaningful

Comment: @Derek, that's true and that's how I usually do it myself.  There are cases, however, in which you want to reorder the rows (not applicable to this particular question, since I don't think SQL Server lets you update values in IDENTITY columns) and probably other instances in which a simple counter works out more easily.

Answer (score 6):

Declare the column with the IDENTITY keyword, and simply do not create a PRIMARY KEY constraint on it.