# I need to insert a value based on year_num 

Tags: sql-server

I need to insert a value based on `year_num` (in SQL Server db) using computed column spec

Example:

if year is 2012 then inserting first row it will be `2012_1` next time `2012_2` ...and if year is 2013 then 1st time `2013_1`, next `2013_2`...

**Edited to add:**
This is my table struct:

```
Sales_OrderID numeric(4, 1) 
CustomerId nvarchar(50) 
Prod_Type varchar(50) 
Prod_Family nvarchar(30) 
Order_Qty int 
Order_Date datetime 
Mfg_StDate datetime 
Mfg_Plan_EndDate datetime 
Shipment_Date datetime 
Shipment_Tracking_No varchar(20) 
FinishedQty int 
Order_Status varchar(50) 
Last_ActivitiyTime datetime
```

I need sales_order to be auto computed based on year_num for every year that num must reset to 1 and then incremented.

Answer (score 0):

Use `IDENTITY` and a serial number of the form 2012000001, 20120000002 etc, reseeding as necessary at the New Year. Or have two fields, a year and the serial number.

[SQL Server auto increment a column without primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7418017/sql-server-auto-increment-a-column-without-primary-key)

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/datacenter/how-do-i-reseed-a-sql-server-identity-column/406

Comment: this is my table struct Sales_OrderID numeric(4, 1) 
CustomerId nvarchar(50) 
Prod_Type varchar(50) 
Prod_Family nvarchar(30) 
Order_Qty int 
Order_Date datetime
Mfg_StDate datetime
Mfg_Plan_EndDate datetime
Shipment_Date datetime 
Shipment_Tracking_No varchar(20)
FinishedQty int 
Order_Status varchar(50)
Last_ActivitiyTime datetime i need sales_order to be auto computed based on year_num for every year that num must reset to 1 and then incr

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below query, thanks:

```
WITH CustomTable
 AS (SELECT  YEAR(DateColumnName) AS yearsPosition, ROW_NUMBER() 
            OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(DateColumnName) 
            ORDER BY ( SELECT 0)) RowNumber
       FROM   YourTableName)
    SELECT CAST(yearsPosition AS VARCHAR)+'_'+ CAST(RowNumber AS VARCHAR) 
    FROM CustomTable
```